# Characterization of the zero set of an elementary symmetric polynomial over finite field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Consider an elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $d$ in $n$ variables over a finite field $F_q$. Is there a nice characterization of its zero set?

We are particularly interested in the zero set containing the $n$-tuples in which all co-ordinates are non-zero and distinct, i.e.,
the set $Z=\{ (a_i,i=1,2,\cdots,n)\vert a_i\neq a_j\neq 0\}$.

For example, consider $\sigma_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\sum_{i,j,i\neq j}x_ix_j$ over $Z_{13}$. The zero set $Z$ (in the above sense) has the following characterization:
The non-zero elements in $Z_{13}$ are partitioned as follows:
$(1,3,9),(2,6,5),(4,12,10),(7,8,11)$.
Now any 4-tuple in the zero set has its three entries from the same subset or its four entries  from four different subsets.